# Problem building a list of class objects in python

Tags: python

I'm still new to python, and been stuck playing around with this for a while and would appreciate someone pointing out where I'm going wrong.

Basically I am trying to build a list that contains a number of different objects, with each object having several attributes.

My attempt is simplified and shown below, basically I built a class for this object, containing several values, and then tried to build a list to contain the objects - it doesn't seem to be heading anywhere successful!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
class TagData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tag = []
        self.val = []
        self.rel = []
        self.database = []
        self.description = []

tagvalue='xxx'
tagList=[]
tagList.append(TagData.tag(tagvalue))
tagList.append(TagData.val(val1))
```

Currently I am getting an error saying TagData has no attribute 'tag'

Thanks,

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong. Did it get mangled when you posted it? Otherwise, I don't see how this could even run on the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create an instance of TagData, like this:

```
TagData()
```

This is why you are getting the AttributeError, because when you use TagData.tag(...), you are really trying to call the tag method of the TagData class object, instead of setting a property of a specific instance.

Next, you need to assign to a property or create a method to set it. For example, you could add a method like this to your class:

```
def addVal(self,value):
    self.val.append(value)
```

And then:

```
a=TagData()
a.addVal('value')
tagList.append(a)
```

Or you could do this (if you don't wish to define getters/setters):

```
a=TagData()
a.val.append('text')
tagList.append(a)
```

Do not do all of that on one line, because when you call addVal, it will return None - and then you will append None to your list instead of your object.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their comments - I added an addVal to the class and made a few other changes and it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`[]` declares a list, so your member variables tag, val, rel etc are all list values, but it sounds like they really want to be scalars? So try this in your constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.tag = None
    self.val = None
    # etc
```

Then you'd do something like this to create your objects:

```
td = TagData()
td.tag = tagvalue
td.val = 'foo'
tagList.append(td)
```

If you want to be able to specify tag and val in the constructor call, you need to add constructor arguments. Here's one way:

```
def __init__(self, tag=None, val=None):
    self.tag = tag
    self.val = val
    # etc
```

Then:

```
tagList.append(TagData(tag=tagvalue))
tagList.append(TagData(val='foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you are not instantiating `TagData`. The attributes inside `__init__` are *instance* attributes (note the `self.` prefix used to set them for an instance) and not class attributes. Try the same code with an instance of `TagData` created thus: `TagData()`

The broader problem is that I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do. Without that it is hard to answer your question better. Adding more context to your question would help.